# Integrating a second order non homogeneous ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I took an exam and the teacher didn't solve this problem during the correction. I need to solve $$y''(x)-y(x)=\sin (e^x)$$I was able to find the solution to the homogeneous equation $$y_h(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}$$Can somebody help me find a particular solution. Thanks!
PS: If somebody knows a solution to the following $$\int \frac{\sin (e^x)}{e^x} \textrm{d}x$$ then the differential equation is solved.

Comment: Yeah i'm sorry. I wrote the differential equation incorrectly!

Comment: Already changed it

Comment: I don't think the particular integral has an exact form, apart from in terms of the cosine and sine integrals.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of variation of parameters?

Comment: You mean, imagining a solution and just plug it in to tweak with the parameters until it works???

Comment: I mean setting the particular solution to be 
$$ y_p(x) = v_1(x)e^x + v_2(x)e^{-x}$$

Comment: Seems like you did already because that particular integral is the result of the method. Unfortunately there isn't a closed form, bou can express it as a definite integral if you have initial conditions.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried (and what the teacher told us to try during the correction) but it was to no avail. I think that I will tell him that I couldn't find any solution so he can check whether the point should be taken into account in the exam

Comment: But you did find the solution. The integral just doesn't have a closed form. You can write it as it is 
$v_2(x) = \int e^{-x}\sin (e^x)\,dx$